# How can i upload a picture with nodejs and express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I have a CMS for a food automation system and I'm going to add a part for upload pictures for foods:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <td><input class="styleFormForAddProducts foodpicForAddFood" type="file" name="file"></td>
    <td><input class="styleFormForAddProducts submitForAddFood" type="submit" value="Submit" ></td>
</form>
```

I wrote this code for making a POST request in Express.js:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path, 
        targetPath = path.resolve('./uploads/image.png');
    if (path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase() === '.png') {
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
            if (err) 
                throw err;
            console.log("Upload completed!");
        });
    } else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function () {
            if (err) 
                throw err;
            console.error("Only .png files are allowed!");
        });
    }
});
```

However when I define this `app.use`, I get an error:

> Middleware: app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'/img'}));
>   Error: Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

When I define a middleware like this :

```
app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir:'/img/'}));
```

I don't have any errors but my code doesn't work correctly .

Comment: 1. Your question title has nothing to do with your question - 2. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid - `td` can only be a child of a `tr`

Comment: @ChrisG   tnnnnnnx

Comment: use `multer` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to upload image with node.js and express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663997/simple-way-to-upload-image-with-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :

```
multer  = require('multer'),
upload = multer({ dest: 'views/img' });




app.post('/upload',upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {

});
```

And my form `HTML` form :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <input class="styleFormForAddProducts foodpicForAddFood" type="file" name="file">
    <input class="styleFormForAddProducts submitForAddFood" type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```